# how do i customize the single page loading style css GIF style?

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, ionic3

```
 presentLoading(message) {

this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  dismissOnPageChange: false,
  spinner:'hide',
  content:`<img class="load" src="assets/dual.gif" />`,
});
this.loading.present();
```

}

> I'm buddy to ionic framework. I shown my code here so i need to customize the img for single page only.
>   i can only do the common page style. Advises are appreciated. 
>   **done**

```css
ion-loading{
.loading-wrapper{
  padding:0px 15px !important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can able to show custom loader and custom style for each components.
for eg:

pageA

```
presentLoading(message) {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      cssClass: 'page-a',
      dismissOnPageChange: false,
      spinner: 'hide',
      content: `<img class="load" src="assets/loader-a.gif" />`,
    });
    loading.present();
}

.page-a {
  // STYLE THAT YOU NEED
}
```

pageB

```
presentLoading(message) {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      cssClass: 'page-b',
      dismissOnPageChange: false,
      spinner: 'hide',
      content: `<img class="load" src="assets/loader-b.gif" />`,
    });
    loading.present();
}

.page-b {
  // STYLE THAT YOU NEED
}
```

Also if you want a common loader, the please create a loader service like

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderService {

    public loading: any;

    constructor(publicloadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

    async show(loaderClass, image) {
        if (!this.loading) {
            this.loading = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
                cssClass: loaderClass,
                dismissOnPageChange: false,
                spinner: 'hide',
                content: `<img class="load" src="'+image+'" />`
            });
            this.loading.present();
        }
    }

    async hide() {
        if (this.loading) {
            await this.loading.dismiss();
            this.loading = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Then import the loader service in your page

```
import { LoaderService } from './../loader/loader.service';

constructor(private loader: LoaderService) {
}

async doSubmit() {
    await this.loader.show('LOADER_CLASSNAME', 'YOUR_LOADER_IMAGE');
    ...stuff here
    this.loader.hide();
}
```

in the above case you can show custom class and image, just pass those as argument.